# C++ Greatest Number Verification

Tags: c++

Hey guys, I was assigned to create a program that creates n arrays composed by 10 random integers. The the program should sum all the integers and display the result. After, it has to verify which of the sums is the greatest and it has to display that array and the result. Im having troubles getting it done and would like to get some help!
Thanks once again.
Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
double random(unsigned int &seed);
unsigned int seed = 5;
void generateData(int set[10]);
int sumData(int set[10]);
void checkData(int sumResult, int arrayNumber);
int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    int arrayNumber, sumResult; 
    int set[10];
    do {
        cout << "Number of Arrays to Compare: " << endl;
        cin >> arrayNumber;
    } while (arrayNumber < 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumber; ++i) {
        generateData(set);
        sumResult = sumData(set);
        cout << "Sum --> " << sumResult << endl;
        checkData(sumResult, arrayNumber);
    }
    return 0;
}

double random(unsigned int &seed) {
    const int MODULUS = 15749;
    const int MULTIPLIER = 69069;
    const int INCREMENT = 1;
    seed = ((MULTIPLIER * seed) + INCREMENT) % MODULUS;
    return double(seed) / double(MODULUS);
}

void generateData(int set[10]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        set[i] = int (5 + 6 * random(seed));
        cout << set[i] << " || ";
    }
}

int sumData(int set[10]) {
    int sumTotal = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        sumTotal = sumTotal + set[i];
    return sumTotal;
}

void checkData(int sumResult, int arrayNumber) {
    int largerNumber;
    int tempSet[2];
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayNumber; ++i) {
        if (sumResult > largerNumber) {
            tempSet[i] = sumResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless part of the homework assignment is to implement a "random number generator," there is a `rand` function in `<cstdlib>` that will provide _much_ better pseudorandom numbers than your `random` function implementation (just be sure to seed it by calling `srand`, of course).

Comment: What, exactly is your question?  Where are you having trouble?

Comment: I am having allot of troubles with this assingment. I was assigned to develop a program that generates n number of arrays (asked by the user). Each of the arrays is composed by 10 random integers (I know that my random function is not good but thats the one my professor asked us to use). Then, the program should sum the integers of each array and display the result. Then, the program should verify which of the sums is the greatest and display the array and the sum. How can I verify which of the sums is the greatest?

Answer (score 2):

Your question reads

> create a program that creates n arrays composed by 10 random integers....

- But I can see just ***one*** `int`
  array of size `10`. What you should
  be doing is allocate a 2D array of
  size `arrayNumber X 10`, call it say
  `set`.
- Also you should allocate 1D array of
  size `arrayNumber` named say,
  `sumArray` to hold the sum of each
  array. so `sumArray[i]` will be sum of all the elements of the `ith` array in `set`.
- Next you find the max element and its
  index(say `maxIndex`) in the `sumArray`
- Print the Array at index `maxIndex`
  in `set`, which will be array having
  max sum.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick answer, I know that I only have on int array because I dont know how to make a program that creates 'n' arrays. Can you help me on that part please?

Answer (score 0):

To create arrays of arrays of ints an easy way is to do the following:

```
int **createArrayOfArrays(int number, int lengthOfEach)
{
    int **array_of_arrays = (int**) malloc(sizeof(int*) * number);
    int ix;
    for(ix = 0; ix < number; ix++)
    {
       array_of_arrays[ix] = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * lengthOfEach);
    }
    return array_of_arrays;
}
```

Don't forget to free all the memory at the end, you need to free each array and the array of arrays (one free per malloc).

Answer (score 0):

n array of size 10 each can e made this way in c#

```
int n;
      n=  Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());


    int [,] mat=new int [n ,10];


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            mat[i,j] = 0;

    }
```